# How can I backfill this table?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have an existing table `items`:

```
create table items (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
    -- ... and other columns that aren't of relevance.
);
```

I want to create another table called `item_documents`:

```
create table item_documents (
    id serial primary key,
    item_id integer unique foreign key items(id) on delete cascade,
    document tsvector
    -- ... and other computed columns.
);
```

The `item_documents` table is computed from the `items` table. Any time the `items` table is inserted, updated, or deleted the corresponding `item_documents` record should be recomputed. To facilitate this, I will be eventually creating a trigger on the `items` table to recompute the `item_documents` on insert/update (this is where I want to be once this migration is done).

The main problem I'm facing is that I want to backfill the `item_documents` table. The `items` table is very large. I thought about just doing an `insert/select`:

```
insert into item_documents (item_id, document, ...)
select id, compute_document(id, name, ...), ... from items
```

This has an obvious problem: if a concurrent transaction inserts/updates the `items` table, there will not be a corresponding row in `item_documents`.

My next solution is to add the trigger *before* doing the `insert/select`. This leads to another problem: if a concurrent transaction inserts/updates the `item_documents` via the trigger while the `insert/select` is running, the row is locked because of the unique constraint (this can also cause deadlocks). Similarly, because the `insert/select` locks the rows in the `item_documents` table, it'll block any concurrent transactions from running their trigger. This is especially painful since the `insert/select` to `item_documents` takes at least a minute to run (and there are a lot of concurrent transactions).

My next solution is to add the trigger first, but do the `insert/select` in smaller batches and spread them out over time. I can afford extra time because the feature that is using the `item_documents` table isn't being used until the backfill is complete. My idea with this is that that locks on `item_documents` are only kept until the batch is complete.

Is this the right solution for making sure the tables are synchronized with  reduced locking?

Answer (score 1):

Right, to avoid long transactions you need to do some kind of batching.

I would use this query as basis for updating:

```
SELECT id
FROM items
LEFT JOIN item_documents d ON d.item_id = items.id
WHERE d.item_id IS NULL
LIMIT 10
```

Then, for each item in this queue run the `compute_document` function and populate `item_documents`.

Actually this is doable in single PostgreSQL statement:

```
-- repeat this until done:
INSERT INTO item_documents (item_id, document)
SELECT items.id, compute_document(...)
FROM items
LEFT JOIN item_documents AS d ON d.item_id = items.id
WHERE d.item_id IS NULL -- Process all items without documents,
LIMIT 10                -- but only 10 at a time, to avoid locking;
```

Remember to create essential indexes on relevant columns (`item_id` and `id`) in both tables.

As an alternative, you can use boolean flag to indicate data is processed.

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD is_processed boolean; --nulls!
CREATE INDEX items_todo ON items (id) WHERE is_processed IS DISTINCT FROM true;

-- repeat this until done:
WITH workitem AS (
  INSERT INTO item_documents (item_id, document)
  SELECT items.id, compute_document(...)
  FROM items 
  WHERE is_processed IS DISTINCT FROM true
  LIMIT 10
  RETURNING item_id 
)
UPDATE items
  SET is_processed = true
FROM workitems
WHERE workitems.item_id = items.id;
```